# Loading dynamically sized page with ajax

Tags: css, ajax, jquery

I have a site that is utilizing full width background images as well as dynamically sized divs for single page smooth scrolling.

The link is http://teneo.telegraphbranding.com/.

I want to load about.php via ajax so that the sidebar doesn't have to reload, but I'm not having any luck.

When you click on 'About' in the sidebar the about page is not rendering correctly. It seems like the containers are ignoring the jquery. They should butt up next to the side bar but not go past it, except for the underlying background image.

Im loading the page with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var dropDown = $('.dropdown');
$('h3.about').on('click', function() {
    dropDown.slideDown('fast', function() {
        $('#index-wrap').load('about2.php');
    });
});
});
```

Also, it isn't loading a couple of divs that don't have any content but have background images and are supposed to fill the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var snapshotWrap = $('#snapshot-wrap');
var w = $(window);
w.bind('load resize',function() {
    snapshotWrap.css({ width:w.width(), height:w.height()});
});
```

});

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var snapshotContent = $('#snapshot-content');
var w = $(window);
w.bind('load resize',function() {
    snapshotContent.css({ width:w.width() - 205 });
});
```

});

Am I correctly using jquery/ajax to load the page?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether about.php is loading or not, if it is, then your ajax isn't necessarily the problem, is this just a background image and styling problem?

Comment: about.php is loading. It is bringing in content but it seems to be ignoring all of the other javascript functions about.php is supposed to be using. When I link out right to about.php the javascript loads fine, sizes the div containers to the browser window, etc, but not when I load the page via jquery/ajax.

It is however failing to display divs that are empty but still have a bg image set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load elements of a page with ajax, in order for jquery to use those elements, you have to attach event handlers to those new elements after they have loaded. Look up the documentation for .on() to see how to do this, it will be clear once you've read that page. If you get stuck again, be sure to make a new question.

So instead of using the .click() function you might say:

```
$("#object").on("click", function(event){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that. I appreciate it.